# using script as both library and executable in python packages

Tags: python, package, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

with a python package that has a file `myparser` (no `.py`) is it possible to use that file as both a script in `setup.py` and as library? e.g. to do:

```
mypackage
  mypackage/__init__.py
  mypackage/internals.py
  mypackage/myparser
```

and then in `setup.py` use `myparser` as a script (so that it gets installed in `bin/`) and use it from within the library, e.g. in `internals.py` as:

```
import myparser as mp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a normal `.py` module so it can be imported, and define an entry point. [Automatic script creation](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) will take care of creating a script in `bin` that will call the entry point method.

Comment: so the entry point would be to the `main` of the script (i.e. to `main()` in `myparser`)

Comment: Yes, exactly, or whichever method you like to run as entry point. Pretty much straight forward...